# Install OS X El Capitan on HDD partition without erasing other partitions

Tags: macos, mac

I have a Macbook Pro which has OS X Mavericks installed and I want to upgrade to OS X El Capitan. My HDD is partitioned as follows:

- 500.11 GB TOSHIBA MQ…

  - MACOSX
  - DEV
  - FREETIME

If wish to make a clean install of El Capitan on my Mac, can I install it on the MACOSX partition leaving data on the other two partitions untouched? On the other partitions I have projects and docs that I don't want to miss. I have read many docs on the Internet and every one of them says that all data on the HDD is wiped.

Comment: Your data is indeed going to be wiped.  So you should go ahead and backup your personal files.

Comment: What documents told you the data was going to be wiped?  El Capitan won't touch the other partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do a clean install, you'd use Disk Utility to wipe the old system, then the Installer to install the new OS. What gets erased depends on what you tell Disk Utility to erase. If you select the entire disk before clicking Erase, it wipes the entire disk (all partitions); but if you select just the MACOSX volume, that's all that gets erased.

That said, things sometimes go wrong. If you have data that you don't want to lose, you should have it backed up someplace safe. Not just during reinstalls, but always. Preferably multiple places, since backups also sometimes don't work the way you expect them to. And testing to make sure you can restore from your backups is a really good way to verify that they actually work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is NEVER a bad idea to back up your data, so you should do that anyway.

If you want to do a CLEAN install of El Capitan (i.e. you don't want to upgrade Mavericks), then all you have to do is erase the MACOSX partition.  You will lose all the data on that partition, but you will not lose the other two, and El Capitan will not touch them when doing the install.  The DEV and FREETIME partitions will remain unaffected.